# Subprogram not working

Tags: python, function, python-3.x

I am writing out a code that is about the user entering information about the dimensions of a room. The code contains this subprogram:

```
def area(input_number1, input_number2):
    variable = input_number1 * input_number2
    return variable
```

This subprogram's function is to generate the area of a wall by the user entering the length and width and it returns the area to the user. For some reason, it isn't working?

It returns this error message:

```
TypeError: can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'str'
```

Comment: "the user entering information ". You probably didn't convert the entered input from a `str` to an `int` or `float`.

Comment: Try `print(repr(input_number1), repr(input_number2))`. They are strings, not ints.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to convert the input (string) to int so that you can do calculations

```
  input_number1 = int(input_number1)
```